# Python: Reading Tweets from file, no user info

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm new to python and playing with tweets.

This may be stupid, but I'm running into problems with the tweets user entities. It seems like I am reading the .json file in ok to a dict. I am able to print out tweets in different locations in the dict, such as:
tweet = tweets[7]
print (tweet).

[code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL4zr.png)

When I print print (tweet['entities']) I see hashtags and that kind of stuff.
When I print user keys, they show up.

[code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlEay.png)

But, the problem is when I try to iterate through & print out the contents of user stuff like screen name, location, etc

[code3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brgDQ.png)

```
statuses = []
for tweet in tweets:
    statuses.append(tweet['text']) 

ids = []
for tweet in tweets:
    ids.append(tweet['id_str'])

times = []
for tweet in tweets:
    times.append(tweet['user']['created_at'])

screen_names = []
for tweet in tweets:
    screen_names.append (tweet['user']['screen_name'])
```

Is it a problem with reading in the json? Here is a link to what the tweets look like in the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u2soBW4PnRTuCMLdKODf4oKl9Zz88D7l/view?usp=sharing
Am I just dumb and doing something ridiculously wrong? Thanks so much for helping a newbie. I looked around and couldnt find anything about the user stuff not being there. Sorry if I didnt give all the info needed to help.

Code:

```
    import json

    import tweepy

    import twitter

    tweets = []

    for line in open('tweets5.json'):

      try: 
        tweets.append(json.loads(line))

    except:
        pass

    print (len(tweets))

    tweet = tweets[2]

    print (tweet)

    print (tweet['entities'])

    print (tweet['user'].keys())

    print (tweet['text'])

    print (tweet['id_str'])

    print (tweet['user']['name'])

    print (tweet['user']['location'])
    print (tweet['place'])
    print(tweet['user']['screen_name'])
    print (tweet['geo'])
    print(tweet['user']['created_at'])

    print (tweet['favorite_count'])
    print (tweet['retweet_count'])


 **//errors start here I get a key error for id_str when I try to do IDs, so I tried moving things around to see if any of them would go through successfully & move on, but I get a key error for whatever is in the brackets first.

statuses = []
for tweet in tweets:
    statuses.append(tweet['text']) 

ids = []
for tweet in tweets:
    ids.append(tweet['id_str'])

times = []
for tweet in tweets:
    times.append(tweet['user']['created_at'])

screen_names = []
for tweet in tweets:
    screen_names.append (tweet['user']['screen_name'])
```

This is what the tweet looks like:

```
{"created_at":"Mon Feb 19 04:08:20 +0000 2018","id":965437872395472896,"id_str":"965437872395472896","text":"RT @IronStache: .@SpeakerRyan spent all weekend in Florida, but he wouldn\u2019t even visit Parkland to offer comfort and support. \n\nPaul Ryan w\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Lite\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2510706061,"id_str":"2510706061","name":"Bill McClure","screen_name":"RealBillMcClure","location":"Boca Raton, FL","url":null,"description":"Buck & El's kid, husband, dad, friend of the show. Everything I ever needed to know was learned on the streets of Youngstown, OHIO.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":576,"friends_count":1200,"listed_count":5,"favourites_count":2324,"statuses_count":5541,"created_at":"Tue May 20 15:28:42 +0000 2014","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"3B94D9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/864933232118312960\/kqhxw1LB_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/864933232118312960\/kqhxw1LB_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2510706061\/1504194378","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Mon Feb 19 00:45:19 +0000 2018","id":965386782471872512,"id_str":"965386782471872512","text":".@SpeakerRyan spent all weekend in Florida, but he wouldn\u2019t even visit Parkland to offer comfort and support. \n\nPau\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/t2H4QGJ0s7","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":292083207,"id_str":"292083207","name":"Randy Bryce","screen_name":"IronStache","location":"Caledonia, WI","url":"http:\/\/www.randybryceforcongress.com","description":"Democrat for WI-01. Father, Army veteran, Ironworker, Cancer survivor, Wisconsin4ever. Most tweets mine.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":234147,"friends_count":4069,"listed_count":1130,"favourites_count":21552,"statuses_count":26855,"created_at":"Tue May 03 02:27:46 +0000 2011","utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/667813427\/181a97f32cdd68a3fb6a8e744a68a1b7.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/667813427\/181a97f32cdd68a3fb6a8e744a68a1b7.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/878715837259153410\/LQ0QNz2y_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/878715837259153410\/LQ0QNz2y_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/292083207\/1497557512","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":".@SpeakerRyan spent all weekend in Florida, but he wouldn\u2019t even visit Parkland to offer comfort and support. \n\nPaul Ryan won\u2019t do anything to prevent future attacks. We have to replace him with a Congressperson who will. https:\/\/t.co\/PBFoQ6IHfv","display_text_range":[0,245],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/PBFoQ6IHfv","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.palmbeachpost.com\/news\/trump-palm-beach-mar-lago-meeting-with-house-speaker-paul-ryan\/QisKep1LXdV5zQRZWQ5OLO\/","display_url":"palmbeachpost.com\/news\/trump-pal\u2026","indices":[222,245]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"SpeakerRyan","name":"Paul Ryan","id":18916432,"id_str":"18916432","indices":[1,13]}],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":191,"reply_count":379,"retweet_count":4375,"favorite_count":11011,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/t2H4QGJ0s7","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/965386782471872512","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"SpeakerRyan","name":"Paul Ryan","id":18916432,"id_str":"18916432","indices":[1,13]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"IronStache","name":"Randy Bryce","id":292083207,"id_str":"292083207","indices":[3,14]},{"screen_name":"SpeakerRyan","name":"Paul Ryan","id":18916432,"id_str":"18916432","indices":[17,29]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1519013300404"}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include your code as text in your question, not as an image. Thanks :)

Comment: done! sorry about that, this is my first question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this line

```
print (['user']['screen_name'])
```

Should be:

```
print(tweet['user']['screen_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the same error. KeyError: 'user'

Comment: Can you show the full output of `print(tweets)` please? I might have misunderstood the structure of your data. If it's too big to show all, just show  the first few tweets.

Comment: I got this to print: print (tweet['text'])

print (tweet['id_str'])

print (tweet['user']['name'])
print (tweet['user']['location'])

Comment: The tweets in the json file are huge, it wont let me paste here :( Heres a link to a txt on google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u2soBW4PnRTuCMLdKODf4oKl9Zz88D7l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it doesnt like the for tweet in tweets part either, says invalid syntax

Comment: I'm not able to download that huge file just now. Can you show the output of `print(tweet)` please so I can just see what a single tweet looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the link to go to the txt file with one tweet in it. It outputs a lot of stuff when I print(tweet), it wont let me paste in here, too many characters....but that file should be A LOT smaller. The output looks just like the tweet does in the file.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a fix for the printing screen name line. I can't see any obvious errors in the lines after that. Which ones are still causing errors?

Comment: Thank you! I seem to be able to print out everything I need. Now it just gets to where it loops through everything and gives me an error. It doesn't like that I am using append for some reason. I'm sure there is a way that I can combine all of the for tweet in tweets statements, I was trying to go through step by step. It hiccups when it gets to id=[ ] and gives me an error: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: You need to use parentheses to call append rather than square brackets: `times.append(tweet['created_at'])`

Comment: Ah, ok. I get a key error for id_str when I try to do IDs, so I tried moving things around to see if any of them would go through successfully & move on, but I get a key error for whatever is in the brackets first. Ex: I get a Key Error for user when I try to run through screen_names = []
for tweet in tweets:
    screen_names.append (tweet['user']['screen_name'])